# How to get my own IP address using WinINet functions

Tags: winapi, qt, ip-address, wininet

How can I get my own IP address using [WinINet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) APIs?
If it's not possible using WinINet APIs, counld you please suggest which Win32 library I have to use for this purpose?

I need the library which I can use in my C++ code. I don't need a C# or .NET library.

Actually I have to use it in my Qt application.

Comment: What do you need it for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoud use [`QList<QHostAddress> QNetworkInterface::allAddresses () [static]`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qnetworkinterface.html#allAddresses)

Comment: actually this API give me all the addresses for all the interfaces like loopback and many more which are virtual. I just need that ipaddress of the interface from which I am using internet or lan. Is there any way to find this?

Comment: @Surjya Narayana Padhi You can have any number of interfaces through which you can communicate with hosts on the Internet and on **lans** active **at the same time**.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the public IP address or your interfaces' IP address? The public IP address can be extracted from the page [whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com). The other answer gives you the local IP addresses.